# Counting How Many Rows Have A Certain Criteria in Each Row's String

Tags: excel, vba, string, variables, count

I am trying to count how many rows in a column have a certain criteria in their string. Example data is below:

```
96.001
96.001
96.002
97.0052
1201 - Mining
1201 - Drilling
1205 - Safety
```

This data occurs in column F. I want the code to check the column and count how many different cells contain a decimal in them & assign that count to a variable. So if the variable was X, in the above case **X = 4**.

Really been stuck on this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Load the data into an array and see if the INT() of the number is the same as the number.

Comment: If the data in F is not a number, is it always in the form number - string, like 1201 - Mining?

Comment: Yea so there will be several that have the case 96.001, 97.0052, etc. Then below that are hundreds of strings that have 4 numbers followed by a dash and their description. Ex: 1201-Mining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, load the data into the array and use [`Int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions):

```
Sub foo()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = Range("F2:F8").Value
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Int(arr(i, 1)) <> arr(i, 1) Then
            Dim count As Long
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    Debug.Print count ' returns 4
End Sub
```

EDIT:

Given your updated sample data, perhaps the following?

```
Sub foo()
    Dim count As Long
    count = Application.CountA(Range("F2:F8")) - Application.CountIfs(Range("F2:F8"), "*-*")
End Sub
```

This is equivalent to counting all populated cells that do not contain a  `-`.

EDIT 2:

Even easier, as noted by [@FunThomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599798/funthomas), just use `Count`:

```
Count = Application.Count(Range("F2:F8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Count Cells Containing String

- This example counts cells containing periods no matter what they represent (e.g. just a period, a date, a decimal, or a thousand separator).

```vb
Sub CountCellsContainingStringTEST()
    
    Const RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "F2:F8"
    Const CHAR As String = "."
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(RANGE_ADDRESS)
    
    Dim x As Long: x = CountCellsContainingString(rg, CHAR)
    
    MsgBox x

End Sub

Function CountCellsContainingString( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal SearchString As String, _
    Optional ByVal MatchCase As Boolean = False) _
As Long
    
    Dim CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod
    If MatchCase Then
        CompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        CompareMethod = vbTextCompare
    End If
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        If InStr(1, cell.Text, SearchString, CompareMethod) > 0 Then
            CountCellsContainingString = CountCellsContainingString + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    
End Function
```